# Should you always avoid embarrassing people?

Tags: embarrassment

Following up on a recent question here, if someone asks you a question in a large group setting and mispronounces a word, how should you pronounce that word in your answer?  If you pronounce it right, you would embarrass the person who asked. But if you pronounce it as he did, you would appear less learned, and you should have a right not to want that.

Comment: Mispronouncing a word to avoid embarrassing someone seems silly. But you can usually avoid the awkwardness by not immediately repeating the word. Not sure how this is related to Judaism though. Seems like a better fit for [interpersonal.se].

Comment: @shmosel -- Not embarrassing others in public is a big mitzvah in Judaism.

Comment: So is cooking for shabbos. But I'm pretty sure gefilte fish recipes are off-topic.